# A torus is a $2$-cell attached to a circle?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

[image]

If $h=1$ here, then this says $M \cong D^2 \coprod_f S^1$.  But a circle with a disk attached to it by gluing the edges of the disk and the circle together should be just a disk again.  So what am I misunderstanding here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tsemo has sketched a proof (using CW-structures), that there is no way $D^2 \coprod_f S^1$ is a torus.  If you change the problematic statement to a "wedge of $2h$ circles...", then I think the question makes sense.

That said attaching a $D^2$ to an $S^1$ need not give a disc - there is no reason the attaching map has to be the identity. It could, for example, be given by the map $z\mapsto z^2$ (interpreting $z\in \mathbb{C}$). Then $D^2\coprod_f S^1$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}P^2$.

Answer (score 2):

Let put this in this way, take a 2-torus, and cut it twice along the generators of its fundamental group, you obtain a square where all corners are identified to one points, if you separated the corner, you obtain a disc. So for the torus, you need two circles identified in one point and you attach the disc.

Comment: I'm a little confused by your answer, does that mean the question is wrong because I need two circles identified to a point with a disk attached and $h=1$ implies there's only $1$ circle?

Comment: see this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0H5_h-RB0T8

Comment: I understand that you can construct a torus by identifying the edges of the square, but I don't understand from that video how a torus can be constructed by attaching a $2$-cell to a circle.  If you attach a $2$-cell to a circle you get a disk which isn't homeomorphic to a Torus.

Comment: you cannot obtain the CW-structure of the 2-torus with one circle. You can compute the homology of the 2-torus with a CW-structure and $H_1(T^2,\mathbb{Z})=\mathbb{Z}\oplus\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with CW structures, the book I'm reading hasn't covered them yet.  If $k=1$, Can you explain why specifically $D^2 \coprod _f S^1$ is a torus?  If you identify the boundary of $D^2$ to the circle $S^1$, then it should just be a disk which isn't homeomorphic to a Torus.  What specific part of that last statement am I getting wrong?

Comment: You need to pinch $S^1$ to obtain a bouquet of two circles, then you apply the method of the answer.

Comment: So you're saying I need a bouquet of two circles to make a Torus.  Therefore:  If $k=1$, then I have one circle.  And the question says that if $k=1$ then I have a wedge of $1$ circles, which is just a single circle $S^1$.  The question then says to prove that if $k=1$, then $D^2 \coprod_f S^1$ is a Torus.  But you're saying I need a wedge of two circles to make a Torus, so is the question wrong since I have only one circle here?